# Can`t display DHCP IP Adress leases

Tags: gedit, dhcp

I ve been trying to Display the IP Address leases with:

```
gedit /var/lib/dhcp/dhcp.leases
```

gedit is installed but it still doesn`t work.

> (gedit:6004): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open Display:

Thanks, I look forward to a answer

V.B

Answer (score 1):

It seems your are in a console only installation (no Xserver) or your shell enviroment (DISPLAY variable) is not setup correctly.

Use:

```
less -S /var/lib/dhcp/dhcp.leases
```

then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to view files in console.

You may leave the program `less` by typing <kbd>q</kbd>.